# Potential Flaws With Lattice Based Cryptography?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, blind-signature

From researching post-quantum cryptographic schemes it seems **hash-based** and **lattice-based** algorithms are the most promising (**MQ-based** seem to be covered by patents and have more potential unknowns which could be used to exploit them.)  Hash-based schemes seem like the most reliable, but lack certain features found in lattice-based algorithms like the ability to do blind signatures.

For these reasons I'm curious what the potential issues with lattice-based cryptographic systems are and how likely they are to result in practical issues for implementations (be it key and signature size increases to compensate or hard-stop issues where you simply can't work around them with lattice-based cryptosystems.)

- What key and signature sizes are expected to be secure currently?
- What if new algorithms come along as a worst-case scenario?  (Assuming 256 bits of security in both cases.)

Comment: This question deserves a much better title, at the very least.

Comment: @zhenfeizhang What would you suggest?